# How does one add a resourcePolicy in serverless.yaml for an ECR that will be created on deploy?

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, amazon-ecr

I really want to `sls deploy` this with an ecr policy for the resource so that Lambda can access it. Here's the resource policy. We have an explicit deny in our environment, so I must also update this. When I apply the resourcePolicy directly to ECR it works beautifully.

```json
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "LambdaECRImageRetrievalPolicy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:DeleteRepositoryPolicy",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
        "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:sourceArn": "arn:aws:lambda:${aws:region}:${aws:accountId}:function:base-${self:provider.stage}*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

More information:
serverless.yaml

```yaml
service: lambda-hello
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  region: us-east-1
  ecr:
    images:
      appimage:
        path: .
functions:
  hello:
    image:
      name: appimage
```

And my function code (app.js):

```js
"use strict"

module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log("event", event)
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        message: `Hello, world! Your function executed successfully!`,
      },
      null,
      2
    ),
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Proposed Solution:

Serverless on a deploy is building and pushing an image to ECR. It doesn't need to understand much to do this, it just works. If the ECR Repository isn't found, then it gets created; if the repository is there and configured it will use it. This is good for those that like the magic.

To configure it with the serverless.yaml there are 2 steps. Take your current project (assuming you have already deployed it) and put the repo in as infrastructure prior to configuring the provider.ecr or image options for your lambda. Deploy the stack using serverless and you now have your image repository under this Cloud Formation template that is managed by serverless. Once you push that, any future image configurations will use it.

> Name the ECR Repository as serverless would name it (passing an option?, or, just use the name `serverless-<project-name>-<stage>`

Future updates to the ECR infrastructure will now be made here and reflected in your deployments.

To create ECR Infrastructure given the above hello-world example, the resource section should look like this:

```yaml
resources:
  Resources:
    EcrRepository:
      Properties:
        RepositoryName: serverless-lambda-hello-dev
        RepositoryPolicyText: ${file(./ecr-policy.json)}
      Type: AWS::ECR::Repository
```

ecr-policy.json (this is for stage dev)

```json
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "LambdaECRImageRetrievalPolicy",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:DeleteRepositoryPolicy",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
        "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:sourceArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:*-dev-*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```